# I'm writing a program for a class but I keep coming up with the same error

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program for my for my class, the program has to calculate the circumference of an ellipse with major axis: a and minor axis: b.

This is what I keep getting at the end of the program.

> File "/Users/johndoe/Desktop/class/ellipse.py", line 12, in 
>       ram1 = float(math.pi*[3*(a+b)-math.sqrt((3*a+b)*(a+3*b))])
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Remove those `[]` to begin with. Python is not your high-school notebook. Only round parenthesis are allowed in mathematical expressions (no matter how many internal parenthesis you have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the square brackets, which create a list from the operations inside them. Thus, you're trying to do

```
math.pi*[number]
```

Which doesn't work. You probably want to replace them with regular brackets, in which case the expression returns a number:

```
a=2;b=3
float(math.pi*(3*(a+b)-math.sqrt((3*a+b)*(a+3*b))))
```

returns

```
15.865437575563961
```

Comment: You've replicated the same error given in the original code.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue.